# pdfviewer looks pixelated and flickers when I scroll (OSX10.15.7)

Tags: texmaker

I'm using TexMaker on my mac, with an external screen, and my pdf lettering is pixellated and variable (https://i.stack.imgur.com/VbExz.jpg). When I shift it to my laptop screen, the problem is better than on the external screen, but still noticeable and distracting. It also seems to flicker, for lack of a better word, when I scroll down the pdf. I've read that I should try cm-super, but that didn't seem to make much of a difference. I've also tried resizing the screen with different resolutions, which doesn't seem to help either. If I generate the pdf, it appears fine on the same screen.

I'm quite new here, so I'll try to keep up as best I can.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\author{T}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX!  This seems to mean the compiler doesn't find the type 1 font, and uses bitmap fonts (so-called type 3), which you can check with you pdfviewer. Could you post a minimal, yet complete, code that reproduces your problem?

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, I've edited the original question with my preamble and document. From what I can read on other questions, it seems to be a bitmap font, but I'm unsure how to change it.

Comment: Did you try other pdf viewers? You're using texlive (an older one) and so the PDF should be scalable vector fonts by default. You could post the log file of your compilation of this particular example

Comment: I'm not sure how to post the log file?